# python .whl file (pygame) can not be installed

Tags: python-3.6

I am trying to install pygame, but the system displays the following **error**.

[image]

I tried all files on this [link](https://www.lfd.uci.edu/~gohlke/pythonlibs/#pygame).
But still cannot solve it.

and when I try to find the version of Python, I got such things:

[image]

Can anybody give me a hand? Thanks very much!

Comment: Hi, welcome to stack overflow. Please refer the [ask] link for 
more details on how to ask a question (Do not use links for example) and update your question accordingly.

Comment: Based on what I see, you have downloaded a .whl for python2.7, but your python is 3.6.5, do you think that is correct?

Comment: you mean i download a wrong file? but i also have tried other files, they can not work either.